# Sum of last two items of list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to figure out code for sum of last two item of list. 
All i got now is function which returns the last item of list :

```
last_two([],false).
last_two([H|[]],H).
last_two([_|T], P) :- last_two(T,P).
```

What should it look like to return this:

```
?- last_two([4,5,6,3,6,1,7,3],T).

T = 10

?- last_two([4,5,6,3,6,1,4,5],T).

T = 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Who invents such problems?)

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

last_two(Xs, S) :-
   phrase(( ..., [X,Y] ), Xs),
   S #= X+Y.  % or S is X+Y.

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

There are much faster solutions, but I think above is the easiest to understand - after you understood DCGs.

You suggested to use `false` and a default value. I am a bit skeptical about this.  Why `false` for an empty list? But effectively `0` for the single-elemented list? In Prolog, we can simply fail.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

last_two(Xs, S) :-
   last_two(Xs, 0, 0, S).

last_two([], A, B, S) :-
   S #= A+B.
last_two([B|Bs], _, A, S) :-
   last_two(Bs, A, B, S).
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. There should be `0` instead `false`. I'm running your code on [http://swish.swi-prolog.org/](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/) and it doesn't work correctly. Returns error. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @P.Barbra: Above runs in SICStus and SWI.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to solve this without import(use_module)? I'm really sorry...but my teacher wouldn't be happy if i would have used this in my exam. I'd got F probably.

Answer (score 1):

in SWI-Prolog, you could write

```
last_two(Xs, S) :- append(_, [U,V], Xs), plus(U,V,S).
```

for instance

```
?- last_two([_,U,3],10).
U = 7
```